# Querying nested data from a Firebase Realtime database to populate a ListView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nested

I'm trying to populate a ListView using a query that will retrieve all GroupVaccinations that have a boolean value equal to false i.e. allVaccinated = false. The database is structured like so: [allVaccinated is the condition I'm looking to use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wMSo.png)

The following code is what I've tried but nothing is being rendered:

```
     databaseReferenceGV = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("groupVaccinations");
            groupVaccinationList = new ArrayList<>();
    groupVaccinationList.clear();

        BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.navigation_vaccinations:
                    listView.setAdapter(null);
                    groupVaccinationList.clear();
                    Query toDoVaccinationQuery = databaseReferenceGV.orderByChild("groupVaccinationID/allVaccinated").equalTo(false);
                    toDoVaccinationQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            for(DataSnapshot groupVaccinationSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                for (DataSnapshot vaccinationSnapshot : groupVaccinationSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    GroupVaccination groupVaccination = vaccinationSnapshot.getValue(GroupVaccination.class);
                                    groupVaccinationList.add(groupVaccination);
                                }
                            }
                            AllGroupVaccinationList groupVaccinationInfoAdapter = new AllGroupVaccinationList(ActivityToDoDoses.this, groupVaccinationList);
                            listView.setAdapter(groupVaccinationInfoAdapter);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            throw databaseError.toException();

                        }
                    });

                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_doses:
                    //other action
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
```

I'm not quite sure how to query a firebase database so any help is welcomed! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the following query:

```
databaseReferenceGV.orderByChild("groupVaccinationID/allVaccinated").equalTo(false);
```

Since between the `groupVaccinationID` node and the `allVaccinated` property, there are two more children: `-LXiM ... BX9x` and `-LZk5 ... j8Vz`. To solve this, you can iterate the `DataSnapshot` objects twice using `getChildren()` method (as you already do) but in this case, only the following query is required:

```
databaseReferenceGV = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("groupVaccinations");
```

Then create an if statement client side:

```
if(!groupVaccination.getAllVaccinated()) {
    groupVaccinationList.add(groupVaccination);
}
```

Or you can change your database structure to allow a query based only on a single dynamic node.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by client side... where do I put it?

Comment: In the nested for loop that you are already using, right? You need to add to the list only the items that have the `allVaccinated` property set to `false`.